# Building a project where reference paths are different on 32 and 64 bit machines

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am finding Visual studio is starting to be a bit of a pain when trying to build projects.

Basically as a project some of us are working on 64 bit installs of Windows 7, some are on 32 bit which makes certain references need to look in different places

The main problem at the moment is MVVMLight (but I doubt it is specific to this).

So we have the path like this which works fine in 32 bit but fails in 64 bit (I have also GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4.dll include but as it is in same location haven't included here):

```
<Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries\Silverlight4\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4.dll</HintPath>
  <HintPath Condition="'$(PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE)' == 'x86'">..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries\Silverlight4\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I think it is an issue with the conditional but am not sure what it should be as I didn't create this unfortunately and am not massively familiar with MSBuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your condition to "'$(Platform)' == 'x64'"

Your project must be placed in the specific folder relative to ProgramFiles. This is not good idea.
You should use ProgramFiles environment variable for ProgramFiles folder. Like this:

```
    <Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4">
       <HintPath Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64' or !Exists('$(PROGRAMFILES) (x86)')">$(ProgramFiles)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries\Silverlight4\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4.dll</HintPath>
       <HintPath Condition="'$(HintPath)' == '' ">$(PROGRAMFILES) (x86)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries\Silverlight4\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: I found mention of another property that can be used. So similar to what you say here, but not sure if it is correct: `<HintPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries\Silverlight4\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL4.dll</HintPath>`

Comment: It depends on the MSBuild version you are using. You didn't provide this info. If you are using MsBuild 4.0 you can use MSBuildProgramFiles32. But this property ALWAYS points to 32bit ProgramFiles folder, even on a 64-bit OS. To get the regular program files folder, you can just use $(ProgramFiles). So in your case you can use $(MSBuildProgramFiles32) instead of "$(PROGRAMFILES) (x86)".

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not really familiar with msbuild and so all this helps